# Text overlapping in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This works for bigger screen and shows the way I want but on Mobile, "Right Title" overlaps the "Left Title". Left title should go up but Right Title should be below it but instead, it goes on top of the Left Title.

What should I do?

```
    <div class="IdeathonCover">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="bg-image.jpg">
            <div class="IdeathonLeftTitle">
                <h1>Left Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="IdeathonRightTitle">
                <h1>Right Title</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this method too using the bootstrap 3 layout but it didn't work. The "col-x-12" is not being respected:

```
    <div class="IdeathonCover">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="bgimage.jpg">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                   <div class="IdeathonLeftTitle">
                       <h1>Left Title</h1>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="IdeathonRightTitle">
                       <h1>Right Title</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS used is below:

```
    .IdeathonCover {
        position: relative;
    }
    .IdeathonLeftTitle {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0px 50px 20px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .IdeathonRightTitle {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0px 50px 20px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?!

Comment: Use media query for handling screen resolution what you want i.e for mobile or any device

Comment: I did. I used bootstrap's col-xs-12.

Comment: but haven't used `media-query` as you've used `position:absolute` use `media-query` and make the `relative` for mobile devices.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay  correct try to use media-quey

Comment: i doubt that will work. if i use `relative`, both the text will be out of the background image.

Comment: please provide jsfiddle so we can help in better way..ty

Comment: I got it working with a bit of modification as per the code given by Duncan Tidd. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, as far as I'm aware, there is nothing wrong with using Bootstrap classes within absolute positioned elements. You could try something along the lines of:

CSS:

```
.IdeathonCover {
    position: relative;
}
.IdeathonTitles {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And your html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="IdeathonCover">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="bgimage.jpg" alt="">   
            <div class="IdeathonTitles">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Left title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Right title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Go it working just the way I wanted after a few changes :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in the end of your css file-

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 750px){
.IdeathonLeftTitle { right: 0; }
.IdeathonRightTitle { left: 0; top: 67px; }
}
```

it should help.

Comment: I didn't want to write my own css for media query because i'm already using bootstrap. Makes it inefficient. Thank you though.